# Get item text of spinner on onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I am using ActionBarSherlock to display a spinner:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

I have successfully managed to get the spinner display two options from a string array defined in `strings.xml`:

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.menu_list,
                  R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
       FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  

       if(position==0)
       {
            CalendarFragment frag = new CalendarFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.main, frag);

       }
       else
       {
            ConverterFragment frag = new ConverterFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.main, frag);
       }
       ft.commit();


       return true;
      }
    };

bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

`strings.xml`:

```
  <string-array name="menu_list">
        <item>Calendar</item>
        <item>Converter</item>
    </string-array>
```

The issue is that I want to get the text of the array item that is selected and prepend another string to the selected text and display as the title in the actionbar.

Something like this:

```
"SOMESTRING" + Calendar
```

I would not like to display the SOMESTRING in the string array itself.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `bar.setTitle("SOMESTRING" + item)`?

Comment: `item = arrayAdapter.getItem(position)`

Comment: This displays `"SOMESTRING" + Calendar` when I get the item but this displays the spinner text separately as well. i.e. it displays like this: `"SOMESTRING" + Calendar   Calendar`I want the spinner text to display as title.

Comment: I guess, I misunderstood you. I thought, you want to display `"SOMESTRING" + Calendar` in the ActionBar title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create your own adapter class, loading up your data, and overriding `getView()` to populate your `TextView` with your modified text. This is no different than creating a custom adapter for use with a regular `Spinner`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the only way to do it.